# jQuery not equals to conditions not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am likely missing something very obvious here but I have 2 values I need to check

```
if(data['width'] != 2000 || data['width'] != 750){
    $('.image-warning').show();
}
```

I want to show the image warning if the returned value is not 2000 or 750 but seems to be showing all the time.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your logic is flawed. You can't use a negative check like this with an `or` condition, because if one side fails the other will hit, hence the condition is always true. You need to use a logical `and` condition instead:

```
if (data['width'] != 2000 && data['width'] != 750){
    $('.image-warning').show();
}
```

Comment: Ahh done the trick, just assumed && would mean it would need to meet both requirements not one or the other but seems to have worked lol thanks mate

Comment: Thats what it does mean :) eg. 600 is not 2000 **and** it's not 750, so the condition is true, and the `show()` is called. Likewise, 750 is not 2000 but *is* 750, so the condition fails.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with and upvoted Rory McCrossan's answer. He deserves the "Right Answer Check". However, I would propose to do the following:

```
if ( !(data['width'] == 2000 || data['width'] == 750)){
    $('.image-warning').show();
}
```

Pseudo:

```
if ( is not ( 2000 or 700 )){
    show
}
```

That's same! But why? The thing is to avoid double logic conflict. It is debated that it does not matter but it does. The logic I posted is exact translation of what OP asked. `the returned value is not 2000 or 750`. When a logic is translated to common spoken terms, it becomes easier and avoids confusion.
Let's put this into thought, **If that was not a thing, why did the OP get stuck in it?**